# Simplest way/tool to automate API calls and to save Json results in a file?

Tags: api, editor

What would be the simplest tool/editor (ideally for Mac) to run web API queries (Stateless RESTful web API) in a loop in order to store Json results in a  file ?
Very simple basically, trying just to automate the following :
- a first call to get a list of IDs
- then for each each ID, doing a call to get a few values related to this ID. Values are returned in a Json file, I would like to store them in a file (csv or excel)

To test the queries, I've used "Advanced REST client" to set a request with my authentication information header and do a few API queries tests, it works well but now I basically want to create a script to get the whole set of data which is returned and save in a file. With the idea to run this script from time to time. You can't to that with "Advanced REST client", right?

Sorry it's not (yet!) a super advanced question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, [this is an opinion-based question and not great for the Q&A format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the spirit of helpfulness, though, you might try using a scripting language like JavaScript (via NodeJS) or Python.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) - definitely works on (accursed) Mac